# git undo a checkout of past commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-checkout

so I did `git checkout <past_commit_hashtag>`

but then I want to undo it and go back to the current latest revision

so I did a whole bunch of things:

```
git reset --hard
git checkout <root folder>
git branch -D master
git checkout master
```

nonetheless, I now get an error message `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare file_create_url() etc` which implies that I did not revert back to the latest revision properly...

How do I actually go back to the current revision properly?

`git pull --rebase` reveals that my branch is up to date
moreover `git status` reveals that there are no dirty changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a

```
git reflog
```

To see your local history of moving your HEAD ref around and find the hash of the commit you would like to a return do and

```
git checkout $THATHASH
```

Answer (score 1):

To "undo a checkout" you just need to checkout the revision you need. If you want to revert to some branch just do `git checkout branchname`. Of course if you already executed several random commands not understanding their meaning it can be harder to roll them back.

Answer (score 1):

You were in the *detached HEAD* state, to go back would have been just `git checkout master`. But in the meantime, floundering around you deleted that one (`git branch -D master`)... Congratulations!

`git fsck --lost-found` should show you several commits floating in the air (ones you've abandoned, and your killed `master`). Do a `git checkout` of each one, and look around. If it looks like your lost `master`, do a `git branch master` when there. Check it for sanity. The configuration for that branch (where it fetches from, etc) is lost, and will need to be reconstructed. See `git config`, `git remote` and so.

Also take a look at the ["Maintenance and data recovery"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery) chapger in the git book.

If in *any* doubt, copy the directory containing the repository to a new copy where you can fool around until you know exactly how to recover (no, `git` won't lose any data, but untangling the mess one can create with a few commands is another kettle of fish...)